# Plotting a bar plot in R

Tags: r

My undestanding of bar plot in R is severely limited. maybe thats why I am stuck on something so basic.

So I have this data *df_agg*

```
    Planned.start.date  Parent.Application.Release  Actual.Hours    Estimated.Effort
1   2014/08/20 06:00:00 REL0000802                  4               3
2   2014/09/17 06:00:00 REL0000805                  31              21
3   2014/10/15 06:00:00 REL0000808                  102             74
4   2014/11/19 06:00:00 REL0000809                  78              57
5   2014/12/17 06:00:00 REL0000812                  133             67
6   2015/01/22 06:00:00 REL0002534                  12              1
```

All I want to do is to plot a bar plot with parent.application.realease at the x axis and ActualHours or Estimated.effort in the Y axis

The way I try to do this is

```
barplot(Df_agg$Actual.Hours,names=Df_agg$parent.application.release)
```

It give me an error:

```
'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

I guess try as.vector,this doesn't work too.Why is this happening? and how I can plot the graph as I require

PS:Also I would want to  arrange the order of the bins in the barplot by planned.start.date and maybe included both actual.hours and estimated.effort in the same plot side-by-side in the y axis but right now I am just concentrating on plotting a simple bar plot .

But if you can share on how I can implement the above ideas would really appreciate

Comment: Sorry, but it shouldn't be too hard to find a very nice tutorial explaining how to do this.

Comment: I'm wondering how R is supposed to know that you want ActualHours to be represented when you just give it Parent.Application.Release as input ? Maybe you can start by trying `barplot(Df_agg$Actual.Hours,names=Df_agg$Parent.Application.Release)`?

Comment: yeah you are probably right,I should be looking on  concepts.  I dolook at tutorials and documentation in fact doing it right now , for some reason I find R hard to understand and other technologies I try to learn

Answer (score 2):

Try *ggplot2* package,

```
require("ggplot2")
qplot(x = reorder(Parent.Application.Release,Actual.Hours), y = Actual.Hours, data=df_agg, geom="bar", stat="identity", xlab="Parent Application Release", ylab = "Actual Hours", main = "My bar plot")  + theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]